# failure_message_for_should doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, matcher

I wrote myself a custom matcher, which itself works fine. But the `failure_message_for_should` doesn't work, I still get the default failure message. The `...should_not` works!

My matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_same_dom do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    assert_dom_equal(expected, actual)
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    "Expected the same DOM as #{expected}, but got #{actual}"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "Expected a different DOM than #{expected}"
  end
end
```

Failure messages:

```
Failure/Error: helper.link_to("Dictionary", dictionaries_path).should_not be_same_dom('<a href="/dictionaries">Dictionary</a>')
       Expected a different DOM than <a href="/dictionaries">Dictionary</a>

Failure/Error: helper.link_to("Dictionary", dictionaries_path).should be_same_dom('<a class="x" href="/dictionaries">Dictionary</a>')
     MiniTest::Assertion:
       <"<a class=\"x\" href=\"/dictionaries\">Dictionary</a>"> expected to be == to
       <"<a href=\"/dictionaries\">Dictionary</a>">..
       Expected block to return true value.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that the `assert_dom_equal` method raises an exception instead of returning `false`. RSpec catches the exception and returns the exception message instead of the matcher message.

You should be able to catch this yourself:

```
match do |actual|
  begin
    assert_dom_equal(expected, actual)
  rescue MiniTest::Assertion
    false
  end
end
```